# How to make an object of fix length in local storage

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, local-storage, state

I want to store my radio button values in an object on local storage with index of the object as key of it. What should I do to make fix size array? Also I want to set that object as initial value of my state. I have tried some things, but it does not work out.

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
var obj = {'one': 1,'two': 2,'three': 3 };

localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am making an quiz app in which I want to save my selected answers on localstorage but when i come to previous question to reset my answer and then go onto next question then i don't want new item added in my object.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you make an array with the fix length 5 and all element as A.

```javascript
const LEN = 5;
const arr = new Array(LEN).fill(A);
localStorage.setItem("ID", JSON.stringify(arr))
```